# Showing $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{R})$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have an exercise (not for a class) that asks whether $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{R})$ (field automorphisms) is abelian.  I know that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{R})$ is just the trivial group, but is there a nice way to see that it is abelian without knowing the group?

This is Part (c) of a question and Parts (a) and (b) were that $\operatorname{Aut}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is infinite and nonabelian.

Comment: You mean Aut(R) is trivial ? in the second line you wrote R is the trivial group..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is an automorphism of the field of real numbers the identity map?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/is-an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-real-numbers-the-identity-map)

Comment: @Belgi Fixed. $ $

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is not a duplicate.  I specifically want to answer this question without demonstrating the group is trivial (as stated in the question).

Comment: I see. But I think the best way to see that the group is abelian is given in the answers there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I mean the link above.

Answer (score -1):

$\mathbb R$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space, so every $\mathbb Q$-linear function is in $Aut(\mathbb R)$ and $End_{\mathbb Q}(\mathbb R)$ isn't abelian, so $Aut(\mathbb R)$ isn't abelian.

If you mean $Aut(\mathbb R)$ like the group of ring automorphism of $\mathbb R$, the only one is the identity.

Comment: The OP wants *field* automorphisms.