# Finding $\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ functions satisfying $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(xy) = f(x) f(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

Let $f : \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ be a function such that

(a) $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all real numbers $x, y$

(b) $f(xy) = f(x) f(y)$, for all real numbers   $ x, y$

MY SOLUTION

For $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ it's easy to show $f(kx)=kf(x)$.

Let $y$ be any real and $y=a+b$ where $a\in \Bbb{Z}$.

$f(xy)=f(ax)+f(bx)=af(x)+f(b)f(x)=f(x)f(y)$

From here we get a solution $f(x)=0$ or we get $a+f(b)=f(y) \Rightarrow y-b+f(b)=f(y) \Rightarrow f(b)-b=f(y)-y=c(say)$

So we get $f(x)=x+c$. Putting it in original equation, we get $c=0\Rightarrow f(x)=x$.

Hence we get $2$ solutions $f(x)=0$ & $f(x)=x$.

Is this a correct solution? Or am I losing generality is some step ?

Comment: You are losing some generality when you define $c$. You note that $f(b) - b = f(y) - y$, where $y$ is allowed to be any real number, but you also define $b$ to be $y - a$, where $a$ is an integer. This will not give you all real numbers! What you've done is shown that $f(x) - x$ is constant on the equivalence classes of $x \sim y \iff x - y \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why the constant function $f(x;y)=0$ doesn't work?

Comment: The constant function does work, and is mentioned in the second last line of the question.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is a solution. If you ignore it, you can deduce that $f(1)=1.$ Then, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562845/number-of-ring-homomorphism-from-the-ring-of-real-numbers-to-itself) question, asks the exact same question that you have asked, though it uses a slightly advanced vocabulary.

Comment: So the question is to find the set of all functions that satisfying the equations above or just one exemple of it?

Comment: Is this strictly increasing? That'll imply bijectivity

Comment: From (b) you can show $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$ which with (a) implies it is monotone, hence by Cauchy's functional equation $f(x)=cx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, you have just shown that $f(x)-x=f(y)-y$ when $\{x\}=\{y\} \Big(\{x\}=x-[x]\Big)$.

This is the general proof of $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ and $f(x)f(y)=f(xy)$.

\begin{align}
& \text{let } \begin{cases} P(x, y): f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y). \\ Q(x, y): f(x)f(y)=f(xy). \end{cases} \\
\ \\
P(0, 0): \; & f(0)+f(0)=f(0), f(0)=0. \\ 
P(x, 1): \; & f(x)f(1)=f(x). \\
\text{if } \; & \color{blue}{f(x) \equiv 0}: \text{Solution.} \\
\text{if } \; & \exists x \text{ s.t. } f(x) \neq 0: f(1)=1. \\
\ \\
& \text{For } n \in \Bbb{N}: \\
\ \\
P(1, n-1): \; & f(n-1)+1=f(n). \\
P(1, n-2): \; & f(n-2)+1=f(n-1). \\
& \vdots \qquad \vdots \qquad \vdots \\
P(1, 1): \; & f(1)+1=f(2). \\
& 1=f(1). \\
\therefore \; & f(n)=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n \text{ times}} = n. \\
\ \\
P(n, -n): \; & f(n)+f(-n)=f(0)=0, f(-n)=-n. \\
\therefore \; & \text{For } p \in \Bbb{Z}, f(p)=p. \\
\ \\
& \text{For } p, q \in \Bbb{Z}: \\
\ \\
Q\left(p, \frac q p\right): \; & pf\left( \frac q p \right) = q, f\left(\frac q p \right) = \frac q p. \\
\therefore \; & \text{For } r \in \Bbb{Q}, f(r)=r. \\
\ \\
Q(x, x): \; & f(x)^2=f(x^2). \\
\therefore \; & x \geq 0 \Rightarrow f(x) \geq 0. \\
\ \\
& \text{For } x \geq y ( x-y \geq 0): \\
P(x-y, y): \; & f(x-y)+f(y)=f(x), f(x-y) \geq 0. \\
\therefore \; & f(x) \geq f(y). \\
\Rightarrow \; & f: \text{ monotonically increasing function.} \\
\ \\
& \text{For } x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}: \\
& \text{Assume that } f(x) > x. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \exists r \in \Bbb{Q} \text{ s.t. } f(x)>r>x. \\
\Rightarrow \; & r>x, f(r) \geq f(x), f(r) \geq f(x) > r, f(r)>r. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \text{Contradiction.} \\
\ \\
& \text{Assume that } f(x) < x. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \exists r \in \Bbb{Q} \text{ s.t. } f(x)<r<x. \\
\Rightarrow \; & r<x, f(r) \leq f(x), f(r) \leq f(x) < r, f(r)<r. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \text{Contradiction.} \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & \color{blue}{f(x)=x} \text{ for } \forall x \in \Bbb{R}. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & \boxed{\color{blue}{f \equiv 0, f(x)=x}}. \blacksquare
\end{align}

Comment: Can u elaborate the step $Q(x, x)$ .. how did u conclude if $f(x)≥0 \Rightarrow x≥0$ ?

Comment: One more doubt.. why is $f(r)>r$ a contradiction? Same goes for $f(r)<r$

Comment: @AnAlien Oh... maybe that was my mistake. I was talking about the one side($\Leftarrow$).

Comment: @AnAlien With the previous one, we have $f(r)=r.$ ;)