# Find $ Aut (\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers, field-theory

Find $ Aut (\mathbb{C})$ , the group of automorphisms of field of complex numbers  $\mathbb{C}$ .

My solution :

Take any $\phi\in Aut(\mathbb{C})$ . I think its enough if we know possible values of $\phi(i)$ because if we know $\phi(i)= a$ then we know $1=\phi(1)=\phi(i^4)=a^4$ . So $a=$ roots of equation $z^4=1$ in complex numbers .Lets name them as $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$

Now i can show that $\phi(x)=x a_1$  $\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}$ . I'm not sure what do about $\phi(x)$ when $x\in\mathbb{R}$ . 
If get possible values for $\phi(x)$ when $x\in\mathbb{R}$ i can find $\phi(z)$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$ ( if $z=a+ib $ $ a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\phi(z=\phi(a)+\phi(i)\phi(b)$ )

So i guess finding possible $\phi(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ will solve the problem . 
Alos i would like to share the link if its sheds some light on how to go about solving this problem

[Is an automorphism of the field of real numbers the identity map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/is-an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-real-numbers-the-identity-map)

Comment: If your automorphism is continuous then you can easily find them. Else I believe this is pretty complicate : $\mathbb C \cong \overline{\mathbb Q(X_1, \dots, X_n, \dots )}$ if I am not mistaken, so they are lot of automorphisms as you can see if you don't ask for continuity.

Comment: I think that group is very, very large....something like $\;2^{\aleph_0}\;$ , *at least* ...If you mean "continuous" automorphisms there are much less: two, in fact.

Comment: Nothing about continuity is mentioned in the book . Ironically the problem is from a analysis book .

Comment: I guess it's understood that by automorphism the book mean sbiholomorphism $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$; in that case, all and only such functions are $z\mapsto az+b$ where $a,b\in\Bbb C,\,a\neq0$.

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, a transcendence basis for $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb Q$ must have $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements, and a field automorphism can independently map each of the elements of this basis to, say, either itself or its negative. That gives us at least $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ automorphisms. On the other hand $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ is also the number of _functions_ $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, no matter what their properties are. So there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ automorphisms.

Comment: If we were to assume continuity of automorphism then it seems $\phi(x)=x a_i , i=1,2,3,4 $ would give complete list of continuous automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ , ami i right ?

Comment: No, because $\phi$ must map $1$ to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by automorphism. Do you mean an automorphism group under composition over holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$? Then your solution is $\phi(z) = \lambda z + \beta$ for all $\lambda,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ $\lambda \neq 0$.

Do you mean a continuous automorphism of the field $\mathbb{C}$? Then your choices are $\phi(z) = z, \overline{z}$.

Do you mean an automorphism of the field $\mathbb{C}$ that is not continuous? Well then you need the Absolute Galois Group.

As you can see, your question can be interpreted many ways, it isn't clear what you are asking.

Since this is from an analysis workbook, the answer is probably the first.