# Are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ the only subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ with natural structure as ordered fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, order-theory, ordered-fields, ordered-rings

We know that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ have a unique structure as ordered fields with the usual order, and that $\mathbb{C}$ cannot be realised as an ordered field. Various non-trivial subfields of $\mathbb{R}$, such as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$, have multiple orderings, but I can't yet completely rule out the possibility of there being other subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ with unique order structure.

Clearly any such subfield cannot contain $bi$ for any $b\in\mathbb{R}^\times$. How can I determine whether there are any other possibilities than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I think you want to say "naturally" ordered instead of uniquely order, simply because there's not just one complete order.

Comment: @DavideTrono That's not right - $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ *are* uniquely orderable fields - remember that the ordering must be compatible with the field structure. (Incidentally, while the unique orderability of $\mathbb{R}$ is easy to show, for $\mathbb{Q}$ it takes some thought.)

Comment: In $\Bbb Q$, you can define a number as positive if and only if it's a non-zero number that's a sum of four squares, which makes it a first-order property in the language of fields of characteristic zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about the field $\mathbb{Q} \left ( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}, \ldots \right )$?

Now every element we've added is a square of something (it's the square of the next number we add), so each element we add *must* be positive. This eliminates the choice we have in ordering, and so the ordering should be unique.

This is an adaptation of the usual proof that $\mathbb{R}$ has a unique ordering: There we use the fact that *every* positive number has a square root, while here we just enforce this property for a generating set.

As an aside, we need to do *something* aggressive like this (adding infinitely many elements), since any  $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ admits an ordering for each real root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

**Edit:**

I thought harder about my aside: That means $\mathbb{Q} \left ( \sqrt[3]{2} \right )$ will work too, since there's only one way to embed it into $\mathbb{R}$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: What do you mean by unique ordering? By axiom of choice every set $X$ has an ordering such that $X$ is well ordered, while $\mathbb{R}$ is far from being well ordered with the usual order.

Comment: @DavideTrono a unique ordering as an ordered field.

Comment: @DavideTrono -- we're discussing orderings compatible with the field structure. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) for a definition, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505113/show-that-the-real-field-mathbbr-has-a-unique-ordering-and-indicates-that-o) for the "usual proof" I'm referring to.

Comment: As $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ works so do its conjugate fields! They are isomorphic! In the same vein (assuming the axiom of choice), $\Bbb{C}$ has infinitely many subfields isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$. As an example of a different kind I think that the field $K$ of (compass&ruler) constructible numbers also works. Simply because if $\alpha$ is a positive constructible number, its square root is constructible. Hence $\alpha$ is forced to be positive in any ordering of $K$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen -- Fantastic addition! Iirc you answered another question about ordered rings the other day, right? Nice to see you again ^_^

Answer (score 9):

An ordered field satisfying "For every $x$, either $x$ or $-x$ has a square root" is uniquely orderable and this ordering is definable from the algebraic structure alone (set $a\le b$ iff $b-a$ has a square root). Since this property is expressible by a first-order sentence, we have a model-theoretic way to generate uniquely orderable subfields of $\mathbb{R}$, namely [**elementary extensions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence#Elementary_substructures_and_elementary_extensions): if $A\preccurlyeq\mathbb{R}$ (indeed if $A$ is a $\forall\exists$-elementary substructure of $\mathbb{R}$) then $A$ is uniquely orderable. Combining this observation with the [downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem), we get results like the following:

- There is a countable uniquely orderable subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\pi$.
- Suppose the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) fails. Then there is a uniquely orderable subfield $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ of cardinality strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Of course results like this can be gotten without model theory, but it's neat to observe that model theory provides a simple machine for generating them.

---

Perhaps a bit more interestingly, there are non-Archimedean uniquely orderable fields of every infinite cardinality *(we can construct one by hand, or if we're feeling lazy we can use compactness)*. Since any field of characteristic $0$ and cardinality $\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{C}$ *(note that the algebraic closure will again have cardinality $\le 2^{\aleph_0}$, and the isomorphism type of an algebraically closed field is determined by its characteristic and transcendence dimension)*, this means that there are uniquely orderable non-Archimedean subfields of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm a little bit lost with the model theory references as I have no familiarity with this topic whatsoever.