# Uniquely orderable subfields of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: field-theory, order-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ordered-fields, ordered-rings

I have heard that, unlike $\mathbb{R}$, the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ cannot be realised an ordered field. Is there any way to extend the natural ordering on $\mathbb{Q}$ to a larger subfield of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in a natural way?

Comment: What are the differences between this question and [the one you asked ten minutes earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4156129/11619)? It looks like this is a subset of that. Or are you asking about subfields of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ in particular.

Comment: Yes, subfields of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an answer to your previous question [Are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ the only subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ with natural structure as ordered fields?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4156129/96384) it is mentioned that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ has a unique field ordering. The same holds true for any $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[n]{q}) \simeq \mathbb Q[X]/(X^n-q)$ for $n$ an odd integer $\ge 3$ and $q$ a positive rational number which is not an $n$-th power of a rational.

Now [Hensel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) will show that any given $\mathbb Q_p$ contains many subfields of that form. E.g. $\mathbb Q_2$ contains $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3})$, both $\mathbb Q_5$ and $\mathbb Q_7$ contain $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, $\mathbb Q_{11}$ contains $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5})$ ...