# Are there discontinuous Ring endomorphisms on real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, continuity

It is rather straightforward to prove that the only continuous Ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ onto itself is the identity, as its restriction to rational numbers is the identity.

I wonder if that still holds if one gives up on the continuity hypothesis? In other words, **are all Ring endomorphisms on $\mathbb{R}$ continuous?**

My intuition would be no, because Ring axioms seem to put loose enough constraint on transcendental numbers. Yet I haven't been able to find a construction for a non-continuous endomorphism.

Technical precision: the definition of Ring homomorphism meant in this question is 1-preserving.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/is-an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-real-numbers-the-identity-map) is probably a better dupe target.

Comment: No, but there are discontinuous Abelian group homomorphisms from the additive group of $\Bbb R$ to itself.