# Abelian subgroups of order automorphism group $({\rm Aut}(\mathbb R,\le), \circ )$

Tags: group-theory, real-numbers, order-theory, abelian-groups, book-recommendation

I am searching for any results regarding Abelian subgroups of $({\rm Aut}(\mathbb R,\le), \circ )$, the **order** automorphism group of $\mathbb R$ (order automorphisms of $\mathbb R$ with the composition operation).

Are there any known results on the subject?
Is there any book that covers the particular subject or any relevant monograph?

Comment: In Peter Neumann's lecture notes on infinite permutation groups https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.11564 there are some results on automorphisms of the rational line. Some of these will carry over to the real line.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{R}, \leq)$? If that means the ring [i.e. field] automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ that are order preserving, then the automorphism group is trivial. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/is-an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-real-numbers-the-identity-map?noredirect=1&lq=1). Do you instead mean that $(\mathbb{R}, \leq)$ is being considered only as an ordered set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an automorphism of the field of real numbers the identity map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/is-an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-real-numbers-the-identity-map)